# What or That with not..but

Tags: sentence-construction, word-difference

Do I use "what" or "that" when I use the construction "not..but"?

> 1. Tell him not all that you know but only that he is eager to hear.
> 2. Tell him not all what you know but only what he is eager to hear.

Or maybe after "not" I should use "that" and after "but" I should use "what"?

> 1. Tell him not all that you know but only what he is eager to hear.

Please advise.

Comment: These are grammatical but   moribund forms. You'd get along fine a couple of centuries ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close with your third sentence. "Tell him not all ..." is confusing.  Instead just use "don't".

> **Don't** tell him all (that) you know, but only **what** he wants to hear.

The first two sentences are not idiomatic.

Comment: It's less idiomatic, but you could also replace "what" with "that which".

Comment: @ScottM  good suggestion, although I think "that which" is perfectly idiomatic.

Comment: That which you just said seems a bit of an exaggeration.